# Умножить все четные столбцы матрицы А на вектор x в обратном порядке

Tags: python, numpy

Дан вектор `x` и матрица `А`. Надо умножить все четные столбцы матрицы `А` на вектор `x` в обратном порядке. Результат записать в новую матрицу и  найти сумму ее элементечалов.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([ [2, 1], [2, 2], [4, 3] ])
x = np.array([ [2], [3] ])
b = A.dot(x)
print(b)
```

Этот код умножает матрицу на вектор. Как переделать код, чтобы соответствовал заданию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделаем маску на четные индексы и умножим их на развернутый в обратном порядке вектор

```
m = np.arange(0,A.shape[0],2)
A[m].dot(x[::-1])

array([[ 8],
       [18]])
```

Comment: `A[::2] @ x[::-1]`

Comment: @MaxU оформите ответом, комментарий могут и не заметить :)

Comment: @strawdog, оформил ответом)

Comment: @MaxU ааа! мы не ищем легких путей :)

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться срезами:

```
A[::2] @ x[::-1]
```

---

Результат:

```
array([[ 8],
       [18]])
```

---

Сумма элементов:

```
(A[::2] @ x[::-1]).sum()
# 26
```